# AfterInsert Grails Save

Tags: grails

I have a issue using the event 'AfterInsert' in Grails.

I have two domains

```
Class B {
     A a // instance of A
}

Class A {

    properties
    ...
    def afterInsert() { 
        B.withNewSession {
            log.info(this) // ok 'this' exist
            new B(a:this).save() <-- Fail
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to save an object A, I have this error:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk95c0c1beb108f186"   Détail : Key (a)=(447165928228) is not present
>   in table "a"

I don't know why I have this error because the log.info(this) displays the good object.

Any advices or solution(s) will be really appreciated :)

Thanks for reading

Comment: are you sure, that A is already in the database, to a has no id before you want to try to save B instance? this could be the problem... Why not using the a service method to do this creation of a object graph?

Comment: Hi Mario. I think that 'a' has already an ID, because log.info(this.id) doesn't display 'null' but a value. I know that I can use a service, but I want to understand what is the cause of this error.

Comment: This works for me in a test 2.3.7 app. What version are you using?

Comment: The same version. Grails 2.3.7 and PostGreSQL for the DB